# Website is not showing updated CSS

Tags: css

I have an issue with my website not updating when I make edits to my CSS file. I believe it's sass CSS, and think something may not be linked where it should be.

I use SiteGround to edit my code (File Manager) and am curious if there's a file I missed. I've edited 2 different files so far with the same code edits. These are the only paths that have what I need to edit:

- public_html > wp-content > themes > (my company theme) > dist > assets> CSS > style.css
- public_html > wp-content > themes > (my company theme) > assets> SCSS > layouts > _business-pillar.scss

I also have NGINX SuperCacher installed through SiteGround and feel there might be something there as well. I checked my website for additional cache plugins and have turned off NGINX and flushed all cache, but still, no edits are being shown on my website.

I did research beforehand and there was something about adding a v2 to my style.css code. I didn't want to add anything redundant or that would break my site without checking some forums first.

I'm happy to provide any other details that would help. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: SCSS needs compiling. Are you running anything to do that? Or is style.css the compiled version anyway, so you're effectively making the same change there too?

Comment: If you load the styles.css directly from a new or incognito browser though are you seeing the new version? If not, either something somewhere is caching it or you didn't edit the currently live version / server.

Comment: We can't tell you if you've missed any paths in your company theme though, because we don't know your theme. But styles.css is the usual one. Unless you have a child theme as well that's overriding this CSS?

Comment: Hi Rup. Thank you for your help! In incognito I wasn't seeing any changes, even after waiting for a weekend. It's a custom theme so I'm unsure if it's using any child themes. I only see one theme that has all the files I need to edit, so I assume I don't have a child theme.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Siteground supports SASS compliling on their servers, what that means is if you change or edit the .scss files on the server they don't automatically update the main style.css file that is being used to style your site. If you locate the main .css file that is styling your site you can edit it there but if you have a lot of ongoing edits you will probably need to create a local copy on your desktop/laptop enable the SASS complier on that and then update the .scss files and upload the whole lot back to the siteground server.